# div in background layer

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have div as watermark on page.

```
div {position: fixed;}
```

But in the area which is covered by div, the buttons and links below the DIVs are become un-clickable. To click the element, scroll and move the DIV.

I have even tried with `z-index` property of body element and watermark div.

```
body z-index to 2
watermark z-index to 1
```

that does't work.

how can i solve this issue, So that element which comes below the watermark div can be clicked.

Comment: in situations like these, i have a click-only invisible div above everything else

Comment: Can you try using background-image instead?

Comment: try adding `position: relative` to `body`

Comment: @Jan Dvorak : with relative position, will div move as we scroll page?

Comment: @PoonamBhatt the thing is `z-index` only applies to positioned elements.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak : watermark div position is fixed `{position: fixed;}`

Comment: note that `z-index` affects the clicking order as well as the rendering order. You could use `pointer-events: none`, but that doesn't work in IE.

Comment: @PoonamBhatt if `body` is not positioned, setting its `z-index` will have no effect.

Comment: ok...I also tried it with main container DIV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a poor way to protect the intellectual property.  Even with plain old chrome, you can directly modify/remove the elements.  That said, there are two approaches I know of.

Number one, is the non-standard [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/pointer-events) css property:

```
pointer-events:none;
```

This will allow all clicks to pass through the object. CAUTION:  it is *non-standard*.  See the compatibility chart at the bottom of the MDN link.

The other method of course is `z-index`.  If you just want a watermark on the page, you can use `z-index`, but it won't cover the buttons/links that should be interactive.  The catch is that z-index requires another attribute to work: `position`.  If the element already has a position attribute, leave as is.  Otherwise, give it `position:relative` so that it stays in the document flow (`absolute` and `fixed` take it out of flow).  Lastly, the tree level of the z-indexed element is also important.  Make sure the watermark is closer to the root element.

In conclusion, I think it's a bad idea.  HTML/CSS was not designed for this, but if you feel adventurous, give it a shot.

Comment: What do you mean by "Lastly, the tree level of the z-indexed element is also important."? As long as both elements share the same stacking context, their depth in the DOM tree doesn't matter.

Comment: @JanDvorak That is what I meant just poorly stated.  If you place a higher z-index element elsewhere in the document tree, it may still appear below an element that has a lower z-index (due to it being the child of another non-static element).  If you place the element you want higher closer to the body tag, it has less a chance of having a conflict with other positioned elements. ([sitepoint](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/stacking) explains it better than I can)

Comment: @ Jseph Marikle: thanks for this `pointer-events:none;` As you have mentioned it works in Mozilla...not in IE...

Answer (score 1):

z-index works perfectly - but in your case it wont because here the div is a child of the body.

what you can do is:

put all your contents in a wrapper div, something like:

```
<div class="wrap">
```

and then add the watermark as sibling to this div (same level)

Now assign z-index to both these divs [watermark: 1 and #wrap: 2]

Answer (score 1):

In your case you are giving the `z-index` to body which won't work because body is the parent of all other elements in it.

so what you can do is:

if your watermark is in the body then `z-index:1`

and

if you have `wrapper div` then its `z-index:2` but `wrapper div needs "position:relative"`;

i tried something here: **http://jsfiddle.net/VJN8F/**

used css is this:

```
p{
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;
 }
div{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  z-index:1;
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  border:solid 1px red;
  background:grey;
  opacity:0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with wider numbers for z-index in CSS

```
body{
    z-index:1000;
    }

watermark{
    z-index:-1000;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**I will suggest you try more wider numbers like 0 or -999 for bottom-most div and 999 for top most div**.

I have noticed that browsers sometime don't reflect it properly if you give very small numbers like 1 and 2. This is just based on my personal experience. So i prefer to give more wider numbers.

Comment: "Browsers don't reflect it properly if you give very small numbers like 1 and 2." can you show me your source or an example?

Comment: may be i should use the word sometime.

Comment: A still disagree. Can you show me an example where it does matter?

Comment: @rai.skumar : with 999 for top and -999 for bottom div, bottom div become invisible

Comment: @JanDvorak ofcourse you can argue on that. It's tough for me to show it now unless i actually simulate it..but i have worked for couple of years as UI developer and used to notice this. Not all browsers implement html specification very strongly and that's why you need to take care of browser compatibility and make sure that behavior is consistent across browsers.

Comment: I can't see any reason why 999 should work better than 2. The only thing that might matter is positive/negative.